# open remote csv isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

So I have a rake task that tries to open a csv file like so.

```
task priceupdate: :environment do
  csvtoopen = open('http://www.someurlhere.com/feed.csv')
  csv = CSV.foreach(csvtoopen, :headers=>true)
  csv.each do |row|
    #Stuff to do with rows here
  end
end
```

For some reason when I run this task, it isn't working. (it should be adding each row to the db (which works on other tasks))

I happen to get this error:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Heres the first few lines

```
"CategoryID","CategoryName","CategoryURL","EventID","EventName","EventDate","EventURL","Venue","VenueCity","VenueCountryCode","VenuePostcode","CurrentMinPrice","CurrentMaxPrice","CurrentTickets","PreSaleDate","OnSaleDate","SoldOutDate","CategoryImageURL","CategoryDescription","VenueAddress","VenueState","VenueID","AffiliatesCommissionTier","TopLevelCategory"
"1478","The Gruffalo"
```

Sam

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your CSV file?

Comment: @ArunKumar See edit in a second :)

Comment: If the CSV file you posted is what you're trying to parse, I was able to parse it without any errors. Check whether the first line of the CSV file contains a missing quotation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the CSV file http://api.viagogo.net/feeds/ukeventfeed.csv

There's a leading whitespace in the first line of the file. Thats why ruby complains about the `illegal quoting` on line 1.

To see it for yourself, hit http://csvlint.io/validation/57af7f946373766bd3000407

Comment: Hey there, Have you go any way around this? perhaps gsubing the whitespace?

Comment: @admitme_sam, Wait a minute, I'll update the answer.